# Growing monad type in OCaml

Tags: types, polymorphism, ocaml

I am tyoing around with the idea of composable state monads and figured row polymorphism should be a good way to implement them.

Here is my code:

```
module ObjectStateMonad =
  struct
    (* constrain state to objects *)
    type 'a state = < .. > as 'a

    (* A state monad yields tuple of a state-object and an observable value *)
    type ('a, 'b) monad = 'a state -> ('a state * 'b)

    (* usual bind, just more type parameters *)
    let bind : (('a, 'b) monad) -> ('b -> ('a, 'c) monad) -> ('a, 'c) monad = 
      fun m -> 
      fun f ->
      fun s ->
        let (st, obs) = m(s) in
        (f obs st)

    (* run, as usual *)
    let run m a = m(a)

    (* get does not directly expose the state but requires a "getter" *)
    let get f = 
      let m : 'a state -> ('a state * 'b) = fun s -> (s, f s)
      in m

    (* put requires a "setter" function to modify the state *)
    let put : ('a state * 'b -> 'a state) -> 'b -> ('a, unit) monad = 
      fun upd -> 
      fun b ->
      let m : 'a state -> ('a state * unit) = fun s -> 
    let s2 : 'a state = (upd (s,b)) in (s2, ()) 
      in m
  end
```

The idea is to compose state monads from different sources and automatically infer a type for the composed state, so when I define two getters:

```
let get_count x = (x#get_count : int) ;; 
val get_count : < get_count : int; .. > -> int = <fun>                                                                                       

let get_length x = (x#get_length : int) ;; 
val get_length : < get_length : int; .. > -> int = <fun>
```

I can mix them and obtain the correct result for the composed state:

```
bind (get get_length) (fun _ -> get get_count) ;;
- : (< get_count : int; get_length : int; _.. >, int) ObjectStateMonad.monad = <fun>
```

Unfortunately, it does not really work for the put part:

```
let set_count (x,i) = x#set_count i ;;
val set_count : < set_count : 'a -> 'b; .. > * 'a -> 'b = <fun>
```

It seems to work when I look at put:

```
 put set_count;;
- : '_a -> (< set_count : '_a -> 'b ObjectStateMonad.state; _.. > as 'b, unit) ObjectStateMonad.monad = <fun>
```

But when I try to `bind` the result, something **strange** happens:

```
bind (put set_count 1) (get get_count) ;;
Error: ...
```

The type error contains the following part:

```
< set_count : int -> 'b ObjectStateMonad.state ObjectStateMonad.state;
```

the state -type has **grown**. Why does that happen?

Comment: The type of `put` is not polymorphic: the type `_a` represents a single type that isn't known yet. I think it's called "weakly polymorphic". It's denoted by the leading underscore.

Comment: I think this is just due to partial application.

Comment: yes, it is 'weakly-polymorphic', and can be due to partial application; an eta-expansion usually removes them.